# how to check if images from url is broken

Tags: angular, ionic4

l am working on ionic 4  project . My project is getting data json from url . l want to check if images comes from url is broken or not . if is broken show another images . l am tried  different code but no one is working .

what l am using code is

```
   <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items" justify-content-around test-center>


          <ion-col >
              <img src="/images/data/operators/{{item.flight.airline.code.icao}}_logo0.png"  onerror="this.src='images/data/operators/{{item.flight.airline.code.iata}}_{{item.flight.airline.code.icao}}.png'">

          </ion-col>


        </ion-row>
```

l got error when to run

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Binding to event property 'onerror' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (error)=...
If 'onerror' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module.
```

depending on error if l use `(error)=` l got another error is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 69 in [this.src=
```

any solution please ?

Comment: you have to sanitize it using `DomSanitizer`

Comment: how can l  using DomSanitizer

Comment: refer to this link https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(error) catches error event triggered by img. Use something like:

```
<img src="..." (error)="handleImgError($event, item)">
```

In your component create function handleImgError()

```
function handleImgError(ev: any, item : any){
   let source = ev.srcElement;
   let imgSrc = `images/data/operators/${item.flight.airline.code.iata}_${item.flight.airline.code.icao}.png`;

   source.src = imgSrc;

}
```

Comment: the error is gone , but nothing to show !! , l mean the imges still some of them braking

Comment: Edited. Try now

Comment: :( same ! problem

Comment: Can you check if imgSrc is correct. console.log(imgSrc) before source.src = imgSrc

Comment: l cant do console because l am working on native plugin and he dose not working on browser

Comment: Change first line of function to: let source = ev.srcElement

Comment: when l changed `Change first line of function to: let source = ev.srcElement` every img is broken is Pulsing probably he is cant found `${item.flight.airline.code.iata}_${item.flight.airline.code.icao}`

Answer (score 2):

you should try this. If image not found it will  load an alternative image

```
 <img   class="img-style"  [src]="user.photo ? user.photo : 'https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg'">
```

Comment: l am using link for src ! , check my questing

Comment: <img   class="img-style"  src="your image link? your image link: 'alternative image link'">